# Parallelizing memcpy with OpenMP

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp, memcpy

I need to make copies of two arrays and I'm trying to parallelize the code. I have tried two different ways, but I can't figure out why one is faster than the other.

The first method copies calls `memcpy` for each array in a separate `omp section`. Running this with 16 threads takes 0.063 sec.

```
void copy_uv(void *u, int u_sz, void *v, int v_sz, void *u_copy, void *v_copy) {
    #pragma omp parallel sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
        {
            memcpy(u_copy, u, u_sz);
        }
        #pragma omp section
        {
            memcpy(v_copy, v, v_sz);
        }
    }
}
```

The second method separates the arrays in blocks depending on the number of threads, and each thread copies its own block. The block sizes are a multiple of 64 bytes (the cache line size) to avoid false sharing. The arrays also were allocated with `mkl_malloc(sz, 64)` if relevant. This takes 0.135 seconds with 16 threads.

```
void copy_uv(double *u, int u_sz, double *v, int v_sz, double *u_copy, double *v_copy) {
    int threads = omp_get_num_threads();
    int u_blocksz = ceil((float)u_sz / threads);
    u_blocksz = u_blocksz - (u_blocksz % 64);
    int v_blocksz = ceil((float)v_sz / threads);
    v_blocksz = v_blocksz - (v_blocksz % 64);

    int i,j;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for nowait
        for (i = 0; i < threads; ++i) {
            int index_i = i * u_blocksz;
            if (i == threads-1)
                memcpy(u_copy+index_i, u+index_i, u_sz - index_i);
            else
                memcpy(u_copy+index_i, u+index_i, u_blocksz);
        }
        #pragma omp for nowait
        for (j = 0; j < threads; ++j) {
            int index_j = j * v_blocksz;
            if (j == threads-1)
                memcpy(v_copy+index_j, v+index_j, v_sz - index_j);
            else
                memcpy(v_copy+index_j, v+index_j, v_blocksz);
        }
    }
}
```

It's true that in this case the last thread might have more memory to copy and might take longer than the others, but even if I give it the same amount of memory to copy and ignore the remaining bytes at the end of the array, the time doesn't change.

The results change little if run with fewer threads. With 4 threads, 0.075s and 0.145s. Why does this happen? The first method uses only two threads, and the second uses all of them, so why is it slower? Is the first method better, or am I just doing something wrong with the second method?

Comment: `memcpy` is IO-bound, not CPU-bound.  Splitting it into multiple threads isn't going to help; even if the threads run simultaneously on different CPU cores, those cores will just be competing with each other for memory bandwidth.  You'd proably be better off just copying the arrays in a single therad.

Comment: @Wyzard not true for high performance systems. On server CPUs with many memory channels, a single core can not saturate the memory bandwidth, not even close.

Comment: Please provide a true [mcve], there are too many things missing to give more than a vague generic answer, e.g. `u_sz`, your CPU & memory specifications, compiler versions, measurement methodology, ...

Comment: @Zulan I'm doing this in a remote system. How do I get cpu and memory specs? `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and `cat /proc/meminfo`? If yes, what part of the result should I post here? There are 16 cores and the cpu results are a little long.

Comment: The `model name` will do, although you should know how many sockets of that are in the system. For memory you can look at `lshw`, you should know the number of banks/DIMMs, type (e.g. DDR4), size per bank, clock.

Comment: If this is a high performance system, chances are that the `hwloc` package is installed. `hwloc-info` and `hwloc-ls` could give you hierarchical information about the platform.

Comment: Besides using separate memory controllers, individual threads would need to be on separate page to see a gain.  If you have transparent huge pages, you may not know the page size.

Comment: @tim18 - Why would pages have any impact on multiple threads accessing data? (assuming memory is properly allocated, except for minor TLB usage). What's relevant here is cache line size (64b) and memory transfer size (128b).

Comment: TLB performance may not scale if multiple threads work in the same page.  Ideally, as you said, this effect may be minor.

Comment: Your second code is wrong. omp_get_num_threads() is outside the parallel region, so tells you the number of threads there (likely 1), but you're assuming it's the number inside. What you want is omp_get_max_threads(). (Though that is not entirely safe; you may not get all of them!). Since your second case is effectively only using one thread, it;s no surprise that it's slower...

Comment: Note.. with C++17 std::sort can run parallel if told so.

Answer (score 2):

To take advantage of different IO channels and things like that to have a higher parallel throughput, you'd have to ensure that your threads are mapped to different parts of your architecture (cores, sockets) such that they don't step on their feet, and that they also use memory that is "close".

Generally, OpenMp does not provide much means to specify this in detail.

The `hwloc` toolbox [1] gives you commandline interfaces and an API to deal with these things in a portable way. But usually you would need to program this directly with threads.

[1] https://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/